# Error with recursive IO

Tags: haskell, recursion, io

Why doesn't this code work?

```
xMal 0 _ = return ()
xMal n text =
 do
  text
    xMal (n-1) text
main = xMal (putStrLn t <- getLine) (n <- readLn)
```

I expect to be able to get a number and string as input.

Comment: You aren't using correct syntax, for starters.  FYI, in the future it'd be better to include type signatures for what you think your functions should be, format your code correctly, and include compiler errors.

Comment: What do you think `putStrLn t <- getLine` should be doing?  What does it mean to pass `n <- readLn` as an argument to a function?

Comment: ...and make sure that it is clear what was the expected behavior :)

Comment: `<-` is not an operator; it is part of the syntax of a `do` expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell does not work that way, with your `<-` expressions, you make monadic calls, these should be placed on the correct order. You probably want:

```
xMal 0 _ = []
xMal n text = text : xMal (n-1) text

main = do
    n <- readLn
    t <- getLine
    putStrLn $ show $ xMal n t
```

Here `xMal` is a pure function: `xMal :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> t -> [t]` that replicates the given `t` object `a` times.

`main` is an `IO` monad that reads a line from stdin and parses it as an integer, next it reads a line as a string an finally it shows the replicated string. Something like:

```
*Main> main
15
Hello
["Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello","Hello"]
```

Mind however that your `xMal` already exists: [`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:replicate) already does that.

Comment: worth mentioning that `xMal` then is the same as the standard `replicate` function (from `Prelude`) in this context

Comment: @jd823592: yeah that was why I said "replicates". But answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```hs
   xMal 0 _    = return ()
   xMal n text = do                   -- or, indentation-proof:   
                   text               --  do { text
                   xMal (n-1) text    --     ; xMal (n-1) text }
   main = do {
               t <- getLine
             ; n <- readLn
             ; xMal n (putStrLn t) }
```

it is important to have the same indentation. Otherwise, `{ ; }` are used to delimit the statements in a whitespace-proof fashion. Then, broken indentation doesn't break the code. Still, it's good to line-up our code properly.

`putStrLn t :: IO ()` is an I/O action that prints its string argument `t` on a separate line. It also "produces" a value of type `()` for the next I/O action in chain to react upon; this can be only one value, written as `()` as well, thus denoting an unimportant, throw-away value, a value to be ignored. You could have written `_ <- text` there in your `do` block as well. Writing just `text` has the same effect: the produced value is ignored.

Trying it, in GHCi,

```hs
~> main
hello
3
hello
hello
hello
```